# Segmentation fault when loop printing

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am trying to create a simple voting system that takes the results and graphs them very simply by looping through the makeGraph function printing an asterisk for each vote. When it runs, it takes input and works up until the makeGraph function is run. It prints out thousands of asterisks completely unformatted, then terminates with a "segmentation fault."

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string makeGraph(int val)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < val; i++)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
}

int main()
{
    string title;
    cout << "Enter a title: \n";
    cin >> title;
    int vote;
    int vote1, vote2, vote3 = 0;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter vote option: 1, 2, or 3.\n";
        cin >> vote;
        if (vote == 1)
        {
            vote1++;
        }
        else if (vote == 2)
        {
            vote2++;
        }
        else if (vote == 3)
        {
            vote3++;
        }
    } while(vote != 0);
    cout << title << "\n";
    cout << "Option 1: " << makeGraph(vote1) << "\n";
    cout << "Option 2: " << makeGraph(vote2) << "\n";
    cout << "Option 3: " << makeGraph(vote3) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: `makeGraph()` prints, but does not return anything, yet you're using its return value. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: You should intialize vote1 and vote2 to 0. Current code will only initialize vote3.

Comment: Pass `-Wall` to your compiler, and fix the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `makeGraph` says it is going to return a `string`

```
string makeGraph(int val)
```

Yet there is no `return` value. All you do is write to `cout`.

That means that this will not work

```
cout << "Option 1: " << makeGraph(vote1) << "\n";
```

Because the function is not passing any string value into the out stream.

I would recommend changing the `makeGraph` function as follows.

```
string makeGraph (int val)
{
    string graph = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < val; ++i)
    {
        graph += "*";   // Concatenate to a single string
    }
    return graph;
}
```

Comment: Is there a none type for the function so I don't have to return anything? Or should I really just return 0 and make it an int function?

Comment: yeah, void. But then you only should call the function, don't use cout.

Comment: @Jordan see my edit. I would just recommend fixing the function itself, then the rest of the code should be fine.

Comment: @Jordan If you don't know about functions "returning" `void` then you need to go back you whatever tutorial or book you have, and throw it away. It's one of the basic things that should be early in every book or tutorial on functions.

Comment: Haha thanks man, I was just trying to implement that concatenation but I couldn't figure it out. I'm not sure why it is still spitting out thousands of asterisks though. Something might be up with val, I'm gonna put some print statements in there..

Comment: @Jordan I bet that the problem is with `vote2` and `vote1`. Note that `int vote1, vote2, vote3 = 0;` only initializes `vote3` to 0, the other two are not 0. Try splitting that into three separate statements.

Comment: You could just use the `std::string('*', val)` constructor instead of repeatedly concatenating like that.